# Is it possible to make props conditional in Vue, e.g. prop2 depends on the value of prop1?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js

I have a use case where I need to pass a specific error message to a custom component. If and only if a certain prop is set to `true`. But I doubt `this.required` is available within the props because it will not have been initialized.

```
//custom component
props: {
  required: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  requiredErrorMsg: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: this.required
  }
}
```

Vue (or eslint?) should then throw a warning or error, if the prop is missing depending on whether `required` was set to true or not.

```
<Custom :required="true" /> //missing prop error
<Custom :required="true" required-error-msg="this is an error"/> //no issues
```

---

currently using: 

nuxt v2.3.4

eslint v5.0.1

Comment: did you try wrapping the required prop in a computed?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use **required** as a variable name - it's a reserved word (maybe not for a variable name, but it will get confusing in the end). Maybe **requiredMsg** would be OK.

Comment: the : in front of required makes it a boolean and not a string and the variable name has nothing to do with OP's question :)

Comment: Yes, the **bool** question is OK, but naming does have to do with the question. Try it with a snippet - with **required** it won't work at all, while with **requiredMsg** it will.

Comment: @JC97, using a computed doesn't work, the issue being using `this` inside the prop wont work because it will not have been initialized. **Cannot read property isRequired' of undefined** using a computed named `isRequired` and the prop = `required: this.isRequired`

Comment: @muka.gergely, like @JC97 has said, because of the `:` prefix of `required` it will not matter if the word is reserved or not. But just to provide you some proof, if you change the word `required` to `hihi` you will get: **Cannot read property 'hihi' of undefined**

Comment: I understand that there's a **v-bind:** shorthand before the property, but as it's a reserved word that spells trouble. And that's why I placed my suggestion in a **comment**, **not an answer** - it's not of outmost importance to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue itself never really "throw" an error when a required prop is missing. Vue will only issue a `[Vue warn]`. It's not really mentioned in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/). So to prove it, if you run the snippet below with a missing required prop, you can see it can still render:

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      required:<br>
      {{ required }}
      <br><br>
      requiredErrorMessage:<br>
      {{ requiredErrorMessage }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    requiredErrorMessage: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      required: true  // <-- Explicitly set to true
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-component
    :required="true"
  />
</div>
```

If you want it to actually throw (stop execution), you need to explicitly make it to `throw`, using a `computed` property. If you run the snippet below with an explicit `throw` within a *used* computed property, you should see it will not render at all:

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      required:<br>
      {{ required }}
      <br><br>
      requiredErrorMessage:<br>
      {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    requiredErrorMessage: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    errorMessage(){
      if (this.required === true && !this.requiredErrorMessage)
        // Explicitly call `throw` when required conditions are not met
        throw new Error('Missing prop error.');
        
      return this.requiredErrorMessage;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-component
    :required="true"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can... VUE 3

```
props: {
    prop1: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    prop2: {
        type: String,
        default: (propsListWithValues) => {
            if (propsListWithValues.prop1 == true) {
                return "prop2 now have conditional text by prop1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```